# How to implement an array which starts with it's index as 2

Tags: c++, arrays

How to implement an array in C++ so that the index of the first element is 2. In other words instead of index starting from '0', I want indexing from '2'.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a class to do this... or switch to Pascal.

Comment: Hmm… can you give some background information on why you want to do this (instead of e.g. subtracting 2 from your index value before using it to deference the array?)

Comment: Implement it as a normal array, but subtract 2 when accessing the elements.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2289548/10077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although built-in arrays of C++ have their index starting at zero, you can build an array-like class with an index starting at any number, even a negative one.

The key to building a class like that is overriding the square brackets operator `[]` with an implementation translating the incoming index to the index of the actual array encapsulated within your implementation by subtracting the offset.

Here is a sketch of an implementation that uses `vector<T>` for the data:

```
class array_with_offset {
    int offset;
    vector<int> data;
public:
    array_with_offset(int N, int off)
    :   offset(off), data(N) {
    }
    int& operator[](int index) {
        return data[index-offset];
    }
};
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/aqYL5X)

Comment: Is this a bit of overkill?  I like @CiaPan's answer, a lot simpler.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When you need an offset like 2, yes, it's an overkill. When you want an offset like 200000 or -5, it's not an overkill.

Comment: I would even say that an offset of "2" is dangerous and is not overkill to create a class to handle such "simple" cases.  I have seen too many times when a programmer tries the simple approach and then wound up debugging off-by-1 errors somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Just allocate the array two items longer than you need and ignore items at index 0 and 1.

Comment: The problem with this is not that it wouldn't work in the short run.  The issue occurs (and I've seen it time and again) when a programmer tries to fake out non-zero based arrays in C++ using such simple means.  Somewhere at sometime, the programmer gets "off-by-1" or worse errors.  Better to create a class that can detect misuse than to simply allocate an array.