# C++ Avoiding Triple Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I am trying to create an array of X pointers referencing matrices of dimensions Y by 16. Is there any way to accomplish this in C++ without the use of triple pointers?

**Edit: Adding some context for the problem.**

There are a number of geometries on the screen, each with a transform that has been flattened to a 1x16 array. Each snapshot represents the transforms for each of number of components. So the matrix dimensions are 16 by num_components by num_snapshots , where the latter two dimensions are known at run-time. In the end, we have many geometries with motion applied.

I'm creating a function that takes a triple pointer argument, though I cannot use triple pointers in my situation. What other ways can I pass this data (possibly via multiple arguments)? Worst case, I thought about flattening this entire 3D matrix to an array, though it seems like a sloppy thing to do. Any better suggestions?

What I have now:

```
function(..., double ***snapshot_transforms, ...)
```

What I want to accomplish:

```
function (..., <1+ non-triple pointer parameters>, ...)
```

Below isn't the function I'm creating that takes the triple pointer, but shows what the data is all about.

```
static double ***snapshot_transforms_function (int num_snapshots, int num_geometries)
{
    double component_transform[16];

    double ***snapshot_transforms = new double**[num_snapshots];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_snapshots; i++)
    {
        snapshot_transforms[i] = new double*[num_geometries];

        for (int j = 0; j < num_geometries; j++)
        {
            snapshot_transforms[i][j] = new double[16];

            // 4x4 transform put into a 1x16 array with dummy values for each component for each snapshot
            for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
                snapshot_transforms[i][j][k] = k;
        }
    }

    return snapshot_transforms;
}
```

**Edit2:** *I cannot create new classes, nor use C++ features like std, as the exposed function prototype in the header file is getting put into a wrapper (that doesn't know how to interpret triple pointers) for translation to other languages.*

**Edit3:** After everyone's input in the comments, I think going with a flattened array is probably the best solution. I was hoping there would be some way to split this triple pointer and organize this complex data across multiple data pieces neatly using simple data types including single pointers. Though I don't think there is a pretty way of doing this given my caveats here. I appreciate everyone's help =)

Comment: Yes.  That was easy!

Comment: "*Is there a way*" - Yes.  HOW, you ask?  That is a different question you didn't ask.  It would also help if you would show the code you have that you don't like, and someone will show you a better way to handle it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Ha! Answer accepted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've added some code to show the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Ash That looks like the proper way to do it.

Comment: This answer may be what you're after. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038457/what-is-the-best-modern-c-approach-to-construct-and-manipulate-a-2d-array/53038618#53038618 The question might have been a duplicate but it was closed.

Comment: @Galik Thanks for helping me search around. Though, I need to accomplish this without using any functions offered from std.

Comment: @Ash - for our edification, why is it you `"cannot use triple pointers?"` (other than form and "don't want to"?) If you have in effect a 3D array, you will have 3-levels of indirection. Is there a limitation of the language this is getting put into?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi David. This is an API that is getting thrown into a wrapper to be converted to other languages, and this wrapper I'm restricted to using does not know how to interpret triple pointers. So, I'm trying to figure out how allow a user to pass this 3D data to my function without the use of a triple-pointer-argument. The simplest solution I can think of would be for the user to pass in a single, flattened array of all this data. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way for them to pass this data using 1+ arguments in place of the triple pointer.

Comment: @Ash - makes perfect sense, then it looks like the best approach is to flatten and write a helper to map indexes.

Comment: "this wrapper I'm restricted to using does not know how to interpret triple pointers." This doesn't look like making a lot of sense. Either it accepts pointers and doesn't care about their type (i.e. `void*`)  and then it doesn't really matter if you give it triple or quintuple pointers, all of them are equally good at being `void*`. Or it accepts pointers of a specific type, and then you don't have any freedom in choosing your representation, you have to do what your wrapper expects.

Comment: "this wrapper I'm restricted to using does not know how to interpret triple pointers." -- I am VTC as your question does not include the information needed to answer it; namely, what that wrapper is and what exactly it can or cannot do.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier, better, and less error prone to use an `std::vector`. You are using C++ and not C after all. I replaced all of the C-style array pointers with `vector`s. The typedef `doublecube` makes it so that you don't have to type `vector<vector<vector<double>>>` over and over again. Other than that the code *basically* stays the same as what you had.

If you don't actually need dummy values I would remove that innermost `k` loop completely. `reserve` will reserve the memory space that you need for the real data.

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector; // so we can just call it "vector"
typedef vector<vector<vector<double>>> doublecube;

static doublecube snapshot_transforms_function (int num_snapshots, int num_geometries)
{    
    // I deleted component_transform. It was never used

    doublecube snapshot_transforms;
    snapshot_transforms.reserve(num_snapshots);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_snapshots; i++)
    {
        snapshot_transforms.at(i).reserve(num_geometries);

        for (int j = 0; j < num_geometries; j++)
        {
            snapshot_transforms.at(i).at(j).reserve(16);

            // 4x4 transform put into a 1x16 array with dummy values for each component for each snapshot
            for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
                snapshot_transforms.at(i).at(j).at(k) = k;
        }
    }

    return snapshot_transforms;
}
```

Comment: Don't nest vector like this, your data locality will be ridiculously bad.  Instead flatten the matrix to one dimension (`vector<double>`) and provide a helper for converting from 3D coordinates to flat indexes.

Comment: @Dustin Thanks for the suggestion, though I have to agree with Ben, and I'd rather flatten the 3D matrix than nest vectors. I didn't mention in my OP, but I cannot utilize the many features of C++ here like the std libraries as this bit I'm working on will be thrown into a wrapper and converted to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little bit of object-orientation usually makes the code easier to manage -- for example, here's some code that creates an array of 100 `Matrix` objects with varying numbers of rows per Matrix.  (You could vary the number of columns in each `Matrix` too if you wanted to, but I left them at 16):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>  // for shared_ptr (not strictly necessary, but used in main() to avoid unnecessarily copying of Matrix objects)

/** Represents a (numRows x numCols) 2D matrix of doubles */
class Matrix
{
public:
   // constructor
   Matrix(int numRows = 0, int numCols = 0)
      : _numRows(numRows)
      , _numCols(numCols)
   {
      _values.resize(_numRows*_numCols);
      std::fill(_values.begin(), _values.end(), 0.0f);
   }

   // copy constructor
   Matrix(const Matrix & rhs)
      : _numRows(rhs._numRows)
      , _numCols(rhs._numCols)
   {
      _values.resize(_numRows*_numCols);
      std::fill(_values.begin(), _values.end(), 0.0f);
   }

   /** Returns the value at (row/col) */
   double get(int row, int col) const {return _values[(row*_numCols)+col];}

   /** Sets the value at (row/col) to the specified value */
   double set(int row, int col, double val) {return _values[(row*_numCols)+col] = val;}

   /** Assignment operator */
   Matrix & operator = (const Matrix & rhs)
   {
      _numRows = rhs._numRows;
      _numCols = rhs._numCols;
      _values  = rhs._values;
      return *this;
   }

private:
   int _numRows;
   int _numCols;
   std::vector<double> _values;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   const int numCols = 16;
   std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Matrix> > matrixList;
   for (int i=0; i<100; i++) matrixList.push_back(std::make_shared<Matrix>(i, numCols));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with OO.

Comment: @n.m. it sounds like you don't quite understand the scope of O.O, and think it applies to a narrower range of designs than it actually does.

Comment: It sounds like you don't quite understand the scope of O.O, and think it applies to a broader range of designs than it actually does. Creating a class is not OO. STL is not OO. Ask Alex Stepanov.

Comment: "Encapsulation is one of the fundamentals of OOP (object-oriented programming). It refers to the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)

Comment: "OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and extreme *late binding* of all things" (Alan Kay, the inventor of the term).

Comment: "STL is not object oriented" (Alex Stepanov). According to you, std::vector is OO. Whom do I believe?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks for the suggestion, though for my use case I am not particularly looking for an oo approach. I'm exposing an API with a triple pointer parameter (a parameter which I'm trying to decompose), and internally writing some autotests for maintenance of this API (and should not be creating new classes in doing this).