# C++ - How to use shared_ptr to replace T**

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I am trying to use shared_ptr to replace the C-Style pointer to avoid the memory leak.

```
T** list_of_T;
```

This is my old code. And I try to use shared_ptr in this way:

```
vector<shared_ptr<T>> vector_Of_Tptr;
```

But I think vector will use more memory, and I should rewrite some of my code. So could I change the code in some way like?

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<T> []> shared_list_of_T;
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `std::shared_ptr` does for you here unless you have other objects pointing at the same arrays? Otherwise a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` would make more sense. However that's not particularly efficient so you may want to consider wrapping a one dimension array in a class that presents a two dimensional view, a bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038457/what-is-the-best-modern-c-approach-to-construct-and-manipulate-a-2d-array/53038618#53038618

Comment: Before worrying about the memory overhead, you need to figure out (and tell us) what the lifetime of these objects is and what changes the data structure needs to support.