# How is that pandas is faster than pure C in the groupby operation?

Tags: python, c, pandas, performance, ctypes

I have an nparray of *x,y* pairs with shape `(n,2)`, and knowing for certain that for each *x* there are multiple values of *y* , I wanted to calculate the average value of *y* for each unique *x*. It occurred to me that this needed a `groupby` operation followed by a `mean` which was available in **pandas** library. However, thinking that *pandas* was slow because of the scale of my data (over a million points) I wrote a simple program in *C* and used *ctypes* to call the C function and perform the operation. I used `-fPIC` and compiled a `shared object` file with `GCC MinGW`.

```c
int average( int* array , int size_array , int* unique , int size_unique , float* avg ){

    if (size_array % 2 != 0){
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size_unique ; i++){

        int curX = unique[i];
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0 ; j < size_array ; j += 2){
            if ( array[j] == curX ){
                sum += (array[j+1]);
                count += 1;
            }
        }

        float average = ((float)sum / (float)count);

        avg[i] = average;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Later, because the program was still slow (took about 1.5 seconds) I gave *pandas* a shot and I was stunned at how faster it was using it. It was almost twice as fast as the program I wrote in C. But it didn't make any sense to me. How did they achieve this level of performance? Is pandas using a hashtable?

```py
ar = np.random.randint(0,2000,size = (40000,2))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ar[:,0], 'y': ar[:,1]})
df = df.groupby('y', as_index=False)['x'].mean()
x = df[['x']].to_numpy()
y = df[['y']].to_numpy()
```

I calculated and found out that for an array of size `(40000,2)` and `2000` unique elements, I had about `80,000,000` operation which was done in less than `0.2s`. So each operation takes about *2.5 nanoseconds* which is close to my processor's limit (I have a 3.5Ghz Quad Core CPU - intel i7 4720HQ). So I'm pushing the CPU using the C code. How is it that pandas even push it further?

As I mentioned above, I compiled the C code with GCC MinGW and the following command:
`gcc -fPIC -shared c_out.so c_in.c`.

I used pythons time library to estimate the runtime of the code. I initialized two timestamps one before (`t1`) and one after the code (`t2`). Afterward, I print the time difference between t1 and t2 as the runtime of the code.
Samples of the benchmark for 40000 data ranging from 0 to 2448 are as follows:

```
Run #1
    Pandas: 0.0623
    C: 0.2250

Run #2
    Pandas: 0.0660
    C: 0.1880

Run #3
    Pandas: 0.609
    C: 0.2261

Run #4
    Pandas: 0.0629
    C: 0.2488

Run #5
    Pandas: 0.0619
    C: 0.2159
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365723/why-is-my-python-numpy-code-faster-than-c

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252360/discussion-on-question-by-ark1375-how-is-that-pandas-is-faster-than-pure-c-in-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know pandas but I'm pretty sure that the developers have spend quite some time optimizing the implementation. There are several ways to optimize code. Selecting a good algorithm for the job is one.

Your C code implementation isn't optimized. In contrary it's a very simple brute force implementation that iterates the main array again and again.

So you are comparing things that can't really be compared, i.e. a simple C implementation and a most likely optimized pandas implementation. It's no wonder that the pandas implementation wins.

Also it's important to compile your C code with optimization (typically -O2). It's not clear whether you did that.

I tested your implementation of `average` on my server and compiled it using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror prog.c`. The result was:

```
Using average,    time: 0.2207540000000000
```

Then I turned on optimization, i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 prog.c`. The result was:

```
Using average,    time: 0.0833040000000000
```

Nearly 3 times faster - just by using `-O2` optimization. The lesson is: When measuring performance make sure to turn on a proper optimization level.

Next step... can your implementation be improved?

Here is a first change:

```
struct accu
{
    int sum;
    int count;
};


int average_v1( int* array , int size_array , int* unique , int size_unique , float* avg )
{

    if (size_array % 2 != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    struct accu * accu = calloc(size_unique, sizeof *accu);
    assert(accu != NULL);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < size_array ; j += 2)
    {
      int flag = 0;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < size_unique ; i++)
      {
        if ( array[j] ==  unique[i])
        {
          accu[i].sum += array[j+1];
          ++accu[i].count;
          flag = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (flag == 0)
      {
        puts("Invalid input data\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size_unique ; i++)
    {
      avg[i]  = ((float)accu[i].sum / (float)accu[i].count);
    }

    free(accu);

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is pretty simple:

1. Swap the inner and outer loops, and break out of inner loop when value is matched. On average this will reduce the number of loops to the half.
2. Use dynamic allocated memory to hold intermediate results.

Again using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 prog.c` and running both your `average` and my `average_v1` on the same data set gives me:

```
Using average,    time: 0.0833580000000000
Using average_v1, time: 0.0280810000000000
```

So `average_v1` is nearly 3 times faster!

**But can we do even better?**

Yes, here is a little more complex implementation that uses binary search to find elements in `unique`. Binary search requires a sorted array so a copy of `unique` is made and `qsort` is used. The original array index is also saved in order to get the exact same output.

```
struct sorted_unique
{
    int value;
    int org_index;
};

int comp(const void * a, const void *b)
{
  struct sorted_unique * pa = (struct sorted_unique *)a;
  struct sorted_unique * pb = (struct sorted_unique *)b;
  if (pa->value > pb->value) return 1;
  if (pa->value < pb->value) return -1;
  return 0;
}

int average_v2( int* array , int size_array , int* unique , int size_unique , float* avg )
{
  if (size_array % 2 != 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  struct sorted_unique * psu = malloc(size_unique * sizeof *psu);
  assert(psu != NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < size_unique; ++i)
  {
    psu[i].value = unique[i];
    psu[i].org_index = i;
  }
  qsort(psu, size_unique, sizeof *psu, comp);

  struct accu * accu = calloc(size_unique, sizeof *accu);
  assert(accu != NULL);

  for (int j = 0 ; j < size_array ; j += 2)
  {
    int low = 0;
    int high = size_unique-1;
    int mid;
    int v = array[j];

    // Binary search
    while(1)
    {
      if (low <= high)
      {
        mid = low + (high - low)/2;
        if (psu[mid].value == v) break;

        if (v < psu[mid].value)
        {
          high = mid-1;
        }
        else
        {
          low = mid + 1;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        puts("Invalid input data\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    accu[mid].sum += array[j+1];
    ++accu[mid].count;
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < size_unique ; i++)
  {
    avg[psu[i].org_index] = ((float)accu[i].sum / (float)accu[i].count);
  }

  free(accu);
  free(psu);

  return 0;
}
```

Now I get:

```
Using average,    time: 0.0833030000000000
Using average_v1, time: 0.0279690000000000
Using average_v2, time: 0.0032790000000000
```

So `average_v2` is 25 times faster than `average`.

**But can we do even better?**

Probably... But I'll stop here.

The lesson to learn here is that C isn't just C. The algorithm you select for implementing the function will of cause impact the performance.

Your implementation is way too simple. That's why pandas was faster. An optimized C implementation is likely to be faster than pandas but at least as fast as pandas.

BTW:

> So I'm pushing the CPU using the C code. How is it that pandas even push it further?

Well, tricks can be played to optimize e.g. cache usage, benefit from branch prediction, use special CPU instructions, etc. But I don't think that is the main thing here... Instead the trick is to get the same result by doing less operations by selecting a better algorithm. At least that is step 1.

Comment: "Brute force" O(N) is not necessarily slower than O (log N) binary search though. Back in the days when algorithm theory was invented, it always held true. But this mindset doesn't scale well to data and instruction cache computers with with branch prediction and multicore. The correctly done optimization might as well be parallelization. But since the OP doesn't even know if they compile with optimizations enabled or not, all such discussions are pointless for now.

Comment: @Lundin True. I changed/updated the answer to make my point more clear. Comparing a simple brute force C implementation with a (most likely) highly optimized pandas implementation won't give a meaningful result.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough how grateful I am for your answer. I've been improving the code for a couple of hours now and using the sort really did the trick. Thank you again.

Comment: Besides, I took a look at the implementation of the GroupBy operation in Pandas and I noticed that in fact, it is using a hashtable to compute the mean. That is why it was so much faster than a pure inefficient implementation in C.

Comment: @ARK1375 Great. If my `sort` and `binary search` implementation meets your performance requirements, you are done :-) But as I said: Most likely things can be done to improve it further.

Comment: By the way, [`bsearch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) is also a thing (and unsurprisingly, that page links to `qsort`...)