# Problem while reading and printing an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a newbie and started to code couple of days ago. So today started with array and have some doubts. I'm reading a array by taking input from user and displaying it everything s running fine but on ouput screen I'm having a garbage value and dont know why. Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter a array_size"<<endl;
    cin>>number;

    //Reading and printing array
    int array[number];
    int i=1;
    while(i<=number){
        cin>>array[i];
        i++;
    }
    //printing array
    int j=0;
    while(j<=number){
        cout<<array[j]<<endl;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Expected output: Reading from user: 3

```
1
2
3
//displaying
1
2
3
```

Actual result: Reading from user: 3

```
1
2
3
16
1
2
3
```

Why 16 is showing?

Comment: `int array[number];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector`:  `std::vector<int> array(number);`.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/Pv899Wfb1)

Comment: You are writing from index 1 and reading from index 0.
Besides you are accessing one past the last element.
Eventually, check PaulMcKenzie comment.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: [Arrays always start at zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289548/array-indexing-starting-at-a-number-not-0) and [**Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question: Is your actual question: _Why am I seing `16` instead of some garbage_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: I'm curious where you learned that `int array[number];` (`number` is a variable) is legal C++? Wherever that is please be aware that it is not teaching you correct C++.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget that C-style arrays exist in the language and exclusively use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) & [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) due to indexing out of bounds. The compiler is not obligated to diagnose this, but it means that it is allowed to produce *any* result, including what you expect, something you did not expect, a crash, no output at all, etc - literally *anything* is allowed. C++ does not hold your hand.

Comment: Print `i` during the first loop, and `j` during the second loop and consider the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

**First** `int array[number];` is not standard c++ as `number` is not a constant expression.

**Second**, array indices start as `0` instead of at `1` in c++.

---

There are also many other posts describing these problems.

[Array index always start at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289548/array-indexing-starting-at-a-number-not-0)

[Why accessing out of bound array does not give any error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, c++ does not support VLA (variable length arrays) - see here: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

It was also already mentioned that array indices start at 0, not 1 ([Array indexing starting at a number not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289548/array-indexing-starting-at-a-number-not-0)).

You can avoid these issues using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [ranged-based loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (the latter is available since c++11).

**Code example for you case:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cout << "Enter a array_size" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;

    // Read:
    std::vector<int> array(number);
    for (auto& elem : array)
    {
        std::cin >> elem;
    }

    // Print:
    for (auto const & elem : array)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that `auto elem : array` (without `&`) would not have worked because `auto` by itself would not infer a reference and instead copy the element.

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score -1):

The array should always start at index 0. Update your starting index and the conditions.

```
//Reading and printing array
int array[number];  
int i=0; // should start with zero.
while(i<number){  // should be less than only since you start with zero.
    cin>>array[i];
    
    i++;

}
//printing array
int j=0;
while(j<number){   // should be less than only since you start with zero.
    cout<<array[j]<<endl;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: This is not standard c++. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn more about arrays.

Answer (score -2):

Array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Corrected code:

```
  //Reading and printing array
  int array[number];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < number) {
    cin >> array[i];
    i++;
  }

  //printing array
  int j = 0;
  while (j < number) {
    cout << array[j] << endl;
    j++;
  }
```

It's more idiomatic to use a for loop here:

```
  //Reading and printing array
  int array[number];

  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
  }

  //printing array
  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    cout << array[j] << endl;
  }
```