# Storing pointers in multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

My intention is to create a dynamic 3D array in C++ using pointers.

```
MyType*** myArray;
myArray = new MyType**[GRID_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
  myArray[i] = new MyType*[GRID_SIZE];
  for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; ++j) {
    myArray[i][j] = new MyType[GRID_SIZE];
  }
}
```

Now this 3D array is ready to store `MyType` instances. What is the correct syntax needed when declaring this array if I want to store pointers to `MyType` instead of just `MyType` objects in this array?

Comment: @BlackBear that is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: IMO, this is poor idea. See the code in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216017/dynamical-two-dimension-array-according-to-input/2216055#2216055 for an alternative.

Comment: @Radek: lol if I knew before I wouldn't post my answer. xD

Comment: In C++, you should almost always prefer the safety of `std::vector<T>` to manually managing memory.

Comment: @SethJohnson I agree wholeheartedly, but I'm modifying old code and rewriting everything is not an option.

Comment: @sdfq: You're clearly trying to write your "dynamic 3D array" from scratch, for which you should use `std::vector`. If something else in your program absolutely needs a pointer to an array of floats, then you could perhaps pass it `&(innervec.front())` while making sure that your `vector<vector<vector<MyType> > > >` isn't destroyed.

Comment: @SethJohnson I am replacing an existing array allocated on the stack with this version allocated on the heap. I will try using std::vector instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add another * to your declaration, but don't call new on it.

Comment: I was of course absolutely sure that I had done that and that it didn't work. Well, I tried again and now it worked so I was obviously doing something crazy the first time. This is my dumbest question to date. I'll go and stand in the corner now.

Comment: @sdfqwerqaz: pointers are a mess. Me neither was sure it would work.. ;)