# C++ Overloading : Overloading the [][] operator

Tags: c++, overloading

The question is whether it is possible to overload [ ][ ] .

Well in normal circumstances like vector< vector < int > > , we are overloading the [ ] opertor .

But in cases where if define a special meaning to [ ][ ] is it possible to have such an operator

Comment: there is no `[][]` operator.

Comment: [Another relevant pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no special [][] operator; it's operator[] applied to the result of another operator [].

You can give special meaning to [][] construct by having the first operator returning a special temporary object, which also has [] operator.

Answer (score 12):

No, you will have to overload `[]` to return a value which itself has `[]` overloaded.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, there is no `[][]` operator, it's a `[]`
operator applied to the results of a `[]` operator.  In the most general
case, the first `[]` operator will return a proxy, which implements
itself a `[]` operator.  In the simplest case, the “proxy” 
can be a `T*`, since in C++, pointers implement the `[]` operator.  A
more generic implementation might be along the lines of:

```
class ElementProxy
{
    Container* myOwner;
    int myRowIndex;
    int myColumnIndex;
public:
    ElementProxy( Container* owner, int rowIndex, int columnIndex )
        : myOwner( owner )
        , myRowIndex( rowIndex )
        , myColumnIndex( columnIndex )
    {
    }

    operator Type() const  //  lvalue to rvalue conversion
    {
        return myOwner->get( myRowIndex, myColumnIndex );
    }

    void operator=( Type const& rhs ) const
    {
        myOwner->set( myRowIndex, myColumnIndex, rhs );
    }
};

class RowProxy
{
public:
    RowProxy( Container* owner, int rowIndex )
        : myOwner( owner )
        , myRowIndex( rowIndex )
    {
    }
    ElementProxy operator[]( int columnIndex ) const
    {
        return ElementProxy( myOwner, myRowIndex, columnIndex );
    }
};
```

This isn't perfect; if you are dealing with class types, it's impossible
to support something line `container[i][j].x`, for example; we can't
overload `operator.`.  If you need to support this, about the best you
can do is overload `operator->` on the `ElementProxy`, and require
client code to use `->` instead of `.`, even though it's not really a
pointer, smart or otherwise.

Comment: +1 for the effort of writing so much, illustrating it with an example. :-)

Comment: By the way, why is it `impossible to support something like container[i][j].x`? I think we can. In your code, `ElementProxy` is not needed. Instead if `RowProxy` defines a member `value_type row*`, then  `operator[]` can simply do this : `return row[columnIndex];`. In this way one would able to write `container[i][j].x`.

Comment: @Nawaz If you use `value_type*` as the element proxy, there's no problem.  Suppose, however, you're implementing some sort of sparse matrix, where you don't have complete rows in the form of a C style (sub-)vector.  Or simply where you want to do bounds checking on both the row and the column index.  Once you need a class type for the element proxy, you're stuck; `operator.` won't work.

Comment: Bounds checking can be done even with this approach I suggested. As for sparse matrix, that is a special case, and also I don't know much about it, Or maybe, in that case, we can specialize the template, Or based on the fact whether its sparse matrix or not, we can select `value_type`, and work accordingly.

Comment: @Nawaz It may, in certain cases, be possible to implement bounds checking: rather than returning an `ElementProxy`, the `RowProxy` immediately calls `myOwner->get(...)`.  If this function returns a reference, and the `operator[]` also returns a reference, there should be no problem.  In a lot of cases, however, the elements aren't necessarily present in memory, and you need the `ElementProxy`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators.
To do what you want you must overload operator[] which returns vector of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The subscript operator in c++ is []. when you use a syntax like this "object[][]" you are calling the operator [] to scubscript the first object and then the second operator [] over the object selected by the first.

Substancially you can't overload the operator "[][]" because this operator does not exist. You should overload the subscript operator on the container object and then overload it also in the inner object.