# Overload [][] operator c++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Overloading : Overloading the [][] operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076282/c-overloading-overloading-the-operator)

I have a class matrix, its data is stored in `vector<vector<double> > _data`
and I want to overload the `[][]` operator to return `_data[row][cols]`

I was looking around but couldn't quite understand how to do that using `vector` of `vector`

I know I need to overload the `[]` operator, but it only receives one parameter.

Was thinking of maybe creating an inner helper class but I can't quite get my head around this one.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to initialize the vector of vectors, with [rox][cols] size? if so, i will post an answer

Comment: there is no such thing as the `[][]` operator, so you cannot overload it.

Comment: actually the is, he can access to _data[1][1] if done properly.

Comment: C++ Faq Lite has got [few entries on this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-subscript-op.html).

Comment: *"I want to overload the `[][]` operator to return `_data[row][cols]`"* - I don't understand why you would need to overload it to access that value... default `[]` should be fine.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin Your example uses two `operator[]`s. There is no such thing as `operator[][]`.

Comment: well you can "cheat" and get bi-dimensional vector...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two choices:

1. Create a custom `MatrixRow` class which stores a single row of your matrix. This class can overload `operator[]()` to return an element in the row. Then your matrix class overloads its own `operator[]()` to return a `MatrixRow`.
2. Overload `operator[]()` in your matrix class to return a `vector<double>`. Then you get the second `operator[]()` for free.

Comment: Your answer, to be complete, should point out that the `operator[][]` the OP is asking for does not and cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
double& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
    return _data[row][col];
}

// ...
m(2,4) = 10.3;
```

It's not exactly the same but it is almost as convenient syntactically, and it abstracts away the underlying implementation (so if you decide to use only one vector (1D) and calculate the correct indices to make it appear as 2D, it will be easy to do).

Btw: Using nested vectors has additional memory (and lookup) overhead, which you might not want.

Comment: That is not legal, did you mean `operator()(...`?

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

From what i see, you are trying to create bi-dimensional vector.
So, here is the way you can do it:

```
vector <vector<double>> _data;

vector <double> vec_d; // temporary helpful vector
double d=NULL;

for(int i=0;i<column_size;i++){
            _data.push_back(vec_d);

            for(int j=0;row_size<l;j++)
                _data[i].push_back(d);
    }
```

After doing this, you can acess to your data this way:

```
_data[1][0] = 1.5;
```

Comment: i think that's what he wanted to achive

Comment: I don't even know what this is doing.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: OP didn't write anything about the situation that forces him to overload `[]` operator, he just asked how to overload `[][]` operator (which doesn't exist)

Comment: well, if you read the comments of the question, he replied that it is exactly what he was trying to achive....

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: I see now. You should have write something though, it's not clear at all why you wrote here this snippet of code, what it is supposed to do and how it is supposed to help him. Also your initialization is after the vector object is constructed. What if he needs to initialize it within constructor right when the vector object itself is being constructed... the one to blame here is OP for the way he asked the question... he just didn't provide any details about it.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: Also a side note: I didn't downvote, I'm used to comment and help the author to fix his answer rather than humiliate him because of answering it incorrectly.

Comment: i appreciated you constructive and well explained comment, i am going to edit my answer so it become clear.

Comment: edited, hope i made myself clear

Comment: @Rapptz: hope you get it now...