# Read files by character C++

Tags: c++, file, vector, matrix

I wanted to read a file with numbers
ex:

```
2
2 3 
2 3 4 
5 6 7

3 
2 2
1 2 
2 3
```

I used the getline () function and I store the results in a vector (string). However, when I access the elements in the vector, the entire line with spaces were stored. I wanted to store elements by number (the numbers represent a matrix)

Comment: To read a number: `int x;stream >> x`. There are many question on SO about reading numbers from a stream: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+reading+a+number&submit=search A bit of research before asking is always a good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamical two dimension array according to input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216017/dynamical-two-dimension-array-according-to-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::ifstream file("numbers.txt");
    std::vector<int> data((std::istream_iterator<int>(file)),
                          std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

will give you a vector of integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use just `stream::operator >>` for that.

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

or with file stream:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("input.txt");
    int x;
    f >> x;
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can I use cin to read from a file? wouldn't I have to somehow link cin to read from a file?

Comment: @Josh, `cin` is just an example. `cin` _is a stream_ and you can use another stream instead of `cin`