# Indexing a 3 dimensional array using a single contiguous block of memory

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, arrayaccess, integer-arithmetic

```
vector<bool> working_lattice(box.rect.length * box.rect.height * box.rect.width);
```

How do I access `working_lattice[1][5][3]` using the style of declaration above?

Comment: I know it would look more like `working_lattice[? * ? * ? + ?]`. But how?

Comment: Ignoring, for the moment, the oddities associated with `vector<bool>`, I showed a 3D matrix that you can access using `matrix[a][b][c]` notation in an [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910). For the moment, it passes the size as a template parameter, but it wouldn't take a huge amount to pass it as a ctor parameter instead. If I were writing it today, I'd undoubtedly use an `std::vector` instead of an actual 3D array, which would make it trivial to pass the size to the ctor.

Comment: Three nested vectors would be stored as one contiguous block of memory as well, since each vector itself is stored in a contiguous block of memory. This would also let the machine do the multiplication work for figuring out the offset for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access it as

```
(i * length * height) + (j * height) + k
```

So in your case

```
working_lattice[(i * box.rect.length * box.rect.height) + (j * box.rect.height) + k);
```

or

```
working_lattice[(1 * box.rect.length * box.rect.height) + (5 * box.rect.height) + 3);
```

**EDIT:** Since you mentioned x, y, z elsewhere

```
working_lattice[(x * box.rect.length * box.rect.height) + (y * box.rect.height) + z);
```

Comment: Can the downvoter comment as to why? He already accepted it as the answer too

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether you're using row-major or column-major ordering. Row-major is more typical in C/C++, but you can do either if you're doing it manually.

In row-major ordering, to get to the i, j, k'th element, you need to go through `box.rect.height * box.rect.width * i` elements to get up to the `i`th row, plus `box.rect.width * j` elements to get to the `j`th column of that row, plus `k` to get back to the `k`th element depthwise. To be super-explicit:

```
const size_t n_x = box.rect.length;
const size_t n_y = box.rect.height;
const size_t n_z = box.rect.width;
working_lattice[1 * n_x * n_z + 5 * n_z + 3]
```

This is obviously pretty annoying, so you might want to define an inline function or something to help out.

Answer (score 1):

i.e considering this one:

```
A[R][S][T]
```

assuming that its base address is `addr_base_A`,

so you hope that you can get the address of one specific element `A[i][j][k]`,

the answer I think is: `S*T*i + T*j + k + addr_base_A`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: maybe you could draw a pic to help your understanding, I figured it out by doing this.