# Can I put array inside an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm still confused. Can I do this?

```
int x[y[3]]
```

Array within array?

Is that the correct format?

Thank you!

Comment: dude, What language are you using?

Comment: You don't need to, all you need to do is a two dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you redelman! Just what I needed

Comment: There should be a badge for baiting multiple heavily downvoted answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13672861/179910

Comment: Assuming you can do this (depending on whether it's C or C++, and which particular standard), it's probably not doing what you think. It will get the value of `y[3]` (which hopefully has been defined), and use that to size `x[]`. It's not a 2-dimensional array, as noted by numerous others...

Answer (score 6):

`int x[y[3]];` is valid if `y[3]` is an integral constant expression, and it will declare an array of `y[3]` elements. Otherwise it’s invalid.

---

If you are looking for a 2D array, try the following:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> x;
```

If you want less pain to go through, you can look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html), as suggested by Cat Plus Plus.

Comment: Boost.MultiArray or bust. Or maybe some other multi-dim array implementation, but definitely not vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the assumption that `y[3]` is of an integer type (otherwise it makes no sense), VLA (variable length arrays) are not supported in c++. They are part of C99, but not c++. Therefore, your code is not good.

Some compilers do support VLA, but only as an extension.

Answer (score -6):

It would be something like this

```
int[,] myArray = new int[1][2];
myArray[0][1] = 1;
myArray[1][1] = 1;
```

Comment: That is not valid C++ syntax. If that compiles at all, it is because of some compiler extension. Also you're indexing outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: @DeadMG The lack of Boost isn't even the real issue here.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel does not compile as C# either.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6693430#6693430