# Inserting elements in multidimensional Vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<vector<int>> sort_a;
vector<int> v2;
vector<int> v3;

for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
v2.push_back(i);

  for (int j=0; j<4; ++j) {
  v3.push_back(j);
  sort_a.push_back(v2);
  sort_a.push_back(v3);
  }

}
```

Vector sort_a should be a 4x4 array, instead the output is 31x1 with lots of empty elements, how do i insert elements in a multidimensional vector ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't think of it as a multidimentional vector, think of it as a vector of vectors.

```
int n = 4;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(n, std::vector<int>(n));

// looping through outer vector vec
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // looping through inner vector vec[i]
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    (vec[i])[j] = i*n + j;
  }
}
```

I included parentheses in `(vec[i])[j]` just for understanding.

**Edit:**

If you want to fill your vector via `push_back`, you can create a temporary vector in the inner loop, fill it, and then push_back it to your vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  std::vector<int> temp_vec;

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    temp_vec.push_back(j);
  }

  vec.push_back(temp_vec);
}
```

However, `push_back` calls result in slower code, since not only you need to reallocate your vector all the time, but also you have to create a temporary and copy it.

Comment: This will attempt writing beyond the end of the vectors.

Comment: By reserving elements, i can use [][] method to pass values, but since there was a lot of unwanted allocation i wanted to use pushback and insert values only when needed, how do i do that ?

Comment: @interjay: sorry, for some reason I thought that vectors were already properly resized.

Comment: You don't have to resize inside the loop. You can do it all in the initialization. Just make a size 4 vector full of size 4 vectors.

Answer (score 5):

a `vector<vector<int>>` is not the best implementation for a multidimensional storage. The following implantation works for me.

```
template<typename T>
class array_2d {
    std::size_t data;
    std::size_t col_max;
    std::size_t row_max;
    std::vector<T> a;
public:
    array_2d(std::size_t col, std::size_t row) 
         : data(col*row), col_max(col), row_max(row), a(data)
    {}

    T& operator()(std::size_t col, std::size_t row) {
        assert(col_max > col && row_max > row)
        return a[col_max*col + row];
    }
};
```

use case:

```
array_2d<int> a(2,2);
a(0,0) = 1;
cout << a(0,0) << endl;
```

This solution is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216017/dynamical-two-dimension-array-according-to-input/2216055#2216055).

Comment: You can initialize vector `a` in the constructor initializer list and thus avoid the call to `rezize`. This could avoid one re-allocation.