# How to map a 2D array in a 1D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

Lets say, I have a MxN arrays: `int *b;` and `int **c;` where

1. values in `b` are stored by columns (from `c`) and I need to put values
   from `c` to `b`
2. values in `b` are stored by rows (from `c`) and I need to put values
   from `c` to `b`

I know that basicly I would do it like that:

```
j = index / N;
i = index - (j * M);
```

in order to convert a 1D index into a 2D co-ordinate but have a problem
how to implement those 2 cases, 1) and 2)?

Comment: Consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937325/942596 , It shows how to use a 1D array as a 2D array.

Comment: @ahenderson: yes but is it a row-major order or column-major order there? cause I need both

Comment: The code is for Row-major layout.

Comment: @ahenderson: ok, thanks, so one less :D Maybe you know how to make a column-major order?

Comment: Can't you always get column-major from row_major by using the transpose. so, swap (column, row) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let W be the width of the 2D array, and H its height. Then assuming row-major layout, the 1D index 'ix' relates to the 2D-index [x,y] as such:

```
ix = y*w + x;
y = ix / w;  // implicit floor
x = ix % w;
```

e.g.:

```
const int W = 3, H=2;
int m[H][W] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int* oneD = &m[0][0];
assert(oneD[1*W + 2] == m[1][2]); // element 6, y=1, x=2
```

Comment: great, thank you. How about column-major, is it like this: oneD[1*H+2] == m[1][2]; ? – Brian Brown