# Pointer to a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a pointer  (`*vectorName`) with a 2D vector 366 by 4.

Both

```
vector<int> *vectorName = new vector<int>(366, new vector<int>(4));
```

and

```
vector<int> *vectorName = new vector<int>(366, vector<int>(4));
```

do not work and give me the error

> Error: no instance of constructor "std::vector, <_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with_ty=int, _Alloc=std_allocator]"
>   argument types are (const int, std::vector>*)

What can I do?

This is happening within the main function.

Comment: [Do not use pointers](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp)

Comment: @KonradRudolph That link doesn't seem to be directly related.

Comment: First, there seems to be no reason to use a pointer. Second, you do not have a pointer to a "multi-dimensional vector". You have a pointer to a `vector<int>`. That has one dimension.

Comment: Here is an example of a [multidimensional vector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937325/942596)

Comment: @Dukeling It absolutely is (hint: it’s a presentation, use the left/right keys to navigate).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok, that was not clear at all. Pointers has its uses (just don't ask "like what?"), but I agree with most of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<int> *vectorName = new vector<int>(366, vector<int>(4));
```

The above doesn't work because the **[vector constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) template** (ignoring a few things) looks as follows:

```
vector <TYPE> (SIZE, variable of type TYPE);
```

And in `vector<int>(366, vector<int>(4))`, `vector <int> (4)` is not of type `int`.

**To create a `vector` with 366 elements that are `vector` of `int`s of size 4:**

```
vector<vector<int> > *vectorName = new vector<vector<int> >(366, vector<int>(4));
```

or, **if you don't need a pointer**: (which you quite possibly don't)

```
vector<vector<int> > vectorName(366, vector<int>(4));
```

**As a side note**, if it's a fixed size 2D `vector`, why are you using `vector`, and not just an array. This would be much simpler:

```
int arr[366][4];
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. I'm still new to 2D and 3D vectors.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you're trying to use a pointer to a vector in order to get a dynamic C-array of vectors. There's no reason to do that. You can use a vector of vectors instead:

```
vector< vector<int> >
```

You can initialize that like this:

```
vector< vector<int> > vec(4);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    vec[i].resize(366);
}
```

Usage example:

```
vec[3][365] = 3;
```

If however you really do want a pointer to such a vector:

```
vector< vector<int> >* vec = new vector< vector<int> >(4);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    (*vec)[i].resize(366);
}

(*vec)[3][365] = 3;
```

If your size is constant and you're using a C++11 compiler, you can use an easier way, [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/?kw=array):

```
array<array<int, 366>, 4> arr;

// Usage example
arr[3][365] = 3;
```

Or a pointer to a dynamically allocated one:

```
array<array<int, 366>, 4>* arr = new array<array<int, 366>, 4>;

// Usage example
(*arr)[3][365] = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this? This makes a 2D vector of vectors with int. It creates 366 vectors with a vector with size 4,where all items are initialized to zero. Now you have a 2D vector of 366 by 4.

```
vector<vector<int> > twod( 366, vector<int>(4,0));
```

and if you would like a pointer to this vector:

```
vector<vector<int> >* twodptr = &twod;
```

if you would really need this.