# how to create structure array with dynamic size

Tags: c++

I want to create a structure of array dynamically but i dont know the exact size so it will be added whenever i want...

Consider the following example..

```
 Struct abc
 {
    double **ptrPoints;
    int size;    
  };
```

i am defining pointer variable

```
abc* obj;
```

i dont know the exact size will be so i can not defile like

```
obj = new abc[size];
```

the elements will be added whenever condition satisfied.. i want it like vector but i dont want to use it ....

Please suggest me any way to write the functionality like this...
Thank u

Comment: *"i want it like vector but i dont want to use it"* Why exactly?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::vector` ?

Comment: Use `std::vector`, even if you don't want to use it. Or give a good reason for not wanting it.

Comment: Read; learn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx

Comment: if i use vector then it causes memory leaks

Comment: how are you using the vector? if it's causing memory leaks something's wrong.

Comment: @Jitendra, I laughed aloud. You must be doing something inherently wrong if that's the case. It's not the fault of the vector.

Comment: @Jitendra Wrong. Simply wrong.

Comment: @Jitendra: vector causes memory leaks? you mean the guy who designed vector didn't know enough?

Comment: Have shared pointers as well.

Comment: i am not saying this actualy i have one 2d array within the structure i cant delete it after pushing into vector so i create copy constructor then to i face memory leak issue so i thought the problem will solve if i array instead of vector

Comment: Well, you won't fix that problem by using an array.

Comment: please check my structure again

Comment: why can't you delete it?

Comment: @Jitendra, Again, change the pointers to something that manages its own memory. It's trivial to make a small `Matrix` class if a multidimensional vector won't work for you. And when you said a 2D array, I thought you meant that. You mean you have a pointer to a pointer that acts like a 2D array.

Comment: @chris yes pointer to pointer

Comment: Search for info "shared_ptr" and use it, memory management becomes a lot easier.

Comment: @Jitendra, The most straightforward thing to do would be to do `std::vector<std::vector<double>> points;`, assuming that is, indeed, used as a jagged array.

Comment: @chris thanks i will check this pls share if u have any link regarding this

Comment: @Jitendra, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216017/dynamical-two-dimension-array-according-to-input/2216055#2216055) is a relevant and good read as well.

Comment: +1 to dutt for asking how he's using the vector that's causing memory leaks instead of laughing at the asker's contention.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Does all the leg work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder why you do not want to use vector. But you may initially declare array of sufficient size. Then maintain a counter of the elements being used up. If it has no space then use `realloc`.

Seems the only solution except vectors.

See [THIS](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) for `realloc`

Comment: Please do not use `malloc/realloc/..` for C++. C++ uses new and perhaps has different house keeping rules.

Comment: @EdHeal can I get an idea how to replace `realloc` with `new[]` and `delete[]`

Comment: @Saksham, There's placement new for that purpose. Of course using either is not usually in your best interest.