# copy matrix into where pointer points to in c++

Tags: c++

How to copy a matrix into where a pointer points to?

I am new in c++. I tried a lot but I could not find any solution.

here is my code:

```
float *output = new float[HighRange];
output = new float[10 * 10];    

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
        output[j]=input[i][j]; ---> I have error in this line
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is C++. Why is `output` not a `std::vector<float>` at least?

Comment: Is the first line suppose to be your `input`?  If not, you have a memory leak since you are setting `output` to 2 dynamically created memory blocks without freeing the first.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Use a [wrapper around a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910), for both `input` and `output`, which will allow you to just do `output = input;`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Although agreeable in general, I think the problem is much more basic than that. After all, the expression in question is legal if `input` actually is a 2D-array. Knowing what the compiler complains about would be very helpful ...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to arrange the elements of `input` in `output`. Here is one way:

```
output[i*10 + j] = input[i][j]
```

Comment: @chris: because its size is constant

Comment: @NPE : if the size of the row and column in the matrix(output) are not equal then what will it be?

Comment: @ati: Then it will simply be [i * height + j] where i is in [0, height - 1] and j is in [0, width - 1].

Answer (score 0):

Aside from NPEs suggestion, you have a memory leak here:

```
float *output = new float[HighRange]; // allocate contiguous block HighRange * sizeof(float) bytes
output = new float[10 * 10]; // allocate contiguous block 100 * sizeof(float) bytes
```

Aside from this being unnecessary, you leak memory, i.e. you allocate storage in the first statement that you never free before assigning a new value to the pointer that hold the first address to the previously allocated storage.

When allocating memory dynamically using `new`, you need to make sure you `delete` it accordingly. For arrays, you need to do the following:

```
float *output = new float[HighRange]; // allocate 
delete [] output; // deallocate, note the delete[] operator
output = new float[10 * 10]; // allocate anew
```

**Note:** This is just to display correct usage of new/delete[]. By no means do I suggest your code would be any better if you handled deallocation in your example. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will apply your comments and then get back to you :)

Comment: @ati: Note that my answer cannot possibly have fixed your problem. It Just fixes a problem you didn't know you had.