# Overloading operator [ ] for 3 dimension array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have no problem with overloading operator [] for matrix, but how can I overload it for 3D array, to use code like this `array[2][3][1]`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910

Comment: It's essentially the same approach with one more hop of indirection.

Comment: IF you have a type SomeType variable [10][10][10] define type SomeTypePP and overload its [] to return SomeTypeP and overload SomTypeP [] operator to return SomeType.