# Using [][] operator with vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have created a one dimensional vector of int, how may I treat it like 2 dimensional one?

While I can write `arr[1];` I can't write `arr[1][2];`

Why I need this:
Instead of defining a vector of vectors [3x5] I defined a vector whose length is 15, so every time I have a function that takes coordinations of a place in matrix I have to call another function which converts those into one dimensional value, which is really annoying.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why do you want to access a 1D vector like it's 2D?

Comment: yes exactly @cigien

Comment: because I was supposed to define it as a matrix but for efficiency I used one dimensional vector

Comment: instead of using vector of vectors

Comment: Please add all that information to the question, instead of adding it as comments. Also, try to explain what you mean in code, instead of describing it.

Comment: updated my post @cigien

Comment: It's not gonna be an easy solution, because efficiency sometimes make the coding job harder.  You'll have to treat a single dimensional array/vector as two dimensional, only within your algorithm. e.g. in your case, instead of `arr[1][2]`, you'll write `arr[1 * 5 + 2]`.

Comment: You can treat a 1D array as N dimensional using addressing, or for 2D:

    `arr[x + y * w]`

Where `w` is the "width" of the `y` dimension.

You could use `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` if you want an actual 2D array.

Comment: This isn't (quite) a duplicate question, but the [answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910) to a previous question covers this pretty well nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to treat a 1D array of size `N` as a 2D array with `M` columns, then you can write a helper function that computes the 1D index given 2D indexes:

```
auto in = [M] (int i, int j) { return i * M + j; };
```

and then use it like this:

```
arr[in(i,j)];
```

This is at least preferable to saying `arr[i * M + j]` everywhere, which is error prone.

Ideally, you would wrap this 1D array into a class that supports 2D indexing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best solution is avoid at all the double `operator[]` and define an `at()` function that receive two indexes.

Anyway, if you really (really!) want a double `operator[]` solution, the first one has to return an object with requested data and support the second `operator[]`

I propose the following skeletal example, where a `arr2d` (with compile time known dimension) is based over a mono-dimensional `std::array`.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2>
class Arr2d
 {
   private:
      using int_arr_t = std::array<T, Dim1 * Dim2>;

      int_arr_t  arr{};

   public:
      struct foo
       {
         int_arr_t & arr;

         std::size_t const  i1;

         T & operator[] (std::size_t i2)
          { return arr[i1*Dim1 + i2]; }

         T const & operator[] (std::size_t i2) const
          { return arr[i1*Dim1 + i2]; }
       };

      foo operator[] (std::size_t i1)
       { return {arr, i1}; }

      foo const operator[] (std::size_t i1) const
       { return {arr, i1}; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Arr2d<int, 2, 3>  a2d;

   a2d[1][2] = 3;

   std::cout << a2d[1][2] << std::endl;
 }
```

As you can see, the `arr2d::operator[]` return a `foo` object containing a **reference** to the `std::array` and the first index.

The `foo::operator[]` complete the job, returning a reference (or a constant reference, according the case) to the right element inside the original `std::array`.

But, I repepeat: i prefer a couple of `at()` functions in `Arr2d`

```
T & at (std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2)
 { return arr[i1*Dim1 + i2]; }

T const & at (std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2) const
 { return arr[i1*Dim1 + i2]; }
```

Comment: A nested `std::array` could be used instead of `struct foo`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Do you mean a `std::array<std::array<T, Dim2>, Dim1>`? Yes; and is a simpler and (I suppose) better solution. But I suppose also that the OP want a double `operator[]` over a single array of data.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the comma operator was deprecated inside square brackets with C++20. This will in the future enable to write something like `m[i, j]` for matrix access.

Until then your only chance is to use a member function like `at`.

A clever and not recommended approach is to have `operator[]` return some kind of `row` proxy that has a `operator[]` on its own to perform the indexing. That is shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/SCZ-QB).

Note that storing the `row_proxy` can lead to dangling pointers which is why `operator[]`is only implemented for rvalue references.